# If SharePoint Workflows fail, send an email to SharePoint maintainer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

We are your using SharePoint foundation 2013 and we have document libraries with SharePoint 2010 Workflows. 
Is it possible to implement a workflow to alert us by email when a workflow fails?

Answer (score 0):

If a workflow fails it will not proceed any further so I don’t believe there is a way within the workflow to be notified without custom code. However you could use a 2010 workflow on a secondary list to set up a notification.

For example the workflow starts on an item created in List A: the first step of the workflow is to create an item in List B, then the last step of the workflow is to update the same item in List B (change the “Status” column from 1 to 2 for example).

On List B you have a 2010 workflow that starts when the item is created, waits an appropriate amount of time (depends on your situation but for this example let’s say 1 hour) and then checks the “Status” column. If after an hour the column has not changed to a 2 then the workflow on List B could send out an email alerting someone that the workflow on List A didn’t complete properly.